# Upgrade ServiceStack with Castle.Windsor from 4.x to 5.7

Tags: servicestack, castle-windsor

We upgraded ServiceStack from v4.x to v5.7 for ASP.NET 4.5.2
In v4.x we used Castle.Windsor with PerWebRequst lifecycle. We updated it to LifestyleScoped.
Error we recieved: Scope was not available. Did you forget to call container.BeginScope()?
The question: where should I call BeginScope and how to release it?